# REACT SELECT NO MUESTRA LO SELECCIONADO

Tags: reactjs, select

Estoy trabajando con react select, pero el problema que me ocurre es que cuando realizo la selección de las opciones, no queda seleccionado.
Este es mi codigo

```
<Select
            className="basic-single"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            placeholder="Seleccione el tipo de usuario"
            name="tipoUsuario"
            id="tipoUsuario"
            value={tipoUsuario}
            options={options}
            isSearchable={false}
            onChange={this.cambioValorSelect}
            aria-describedby="helpId"
          />
```

Esta es la funcion del onchange

```
cambioValorSelect = (u) => {
console.log(u.value);
const state = this.state;
state["tipoUsuario"] = u.value;
this.setState({ state, errores: [] });
```

};

Answer (score 1):

Pareciera que tienes que cambiar la parte de value en la declaración de tu componente y cómo estás seteando el estado:

```
<Select
        className="basic-single"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        placeholder="Seleccione el tipo de usuario"
        name="tipoUsuario"
        id="tipoUsuario"
        value={this.state.tipoUsuario}
        options={options}
        isSearchable={false}
        onChange={this.cambioValorSelect}
        aria-describedby="helpId"
      />

cambioValorSelect = (u) => {
    this.setState({ 
        tipoUsuario: u.value, 
        errores: [] 
    });
}
```

Comment: no pude solucionarlo con eso que has dicho

Comment: Entiendo, ¿quizás podrías editar tu pregunta compartiendo como está tu constructor?